# Error at BFS search .Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, console-application

I have this function that will create a BFS .
I have one function and This is my code and :

```
static void Breadth_first_search(Queue<int> Q, List<int > trace, int[,] grid, int start, int nodes)
        {
            int u;
            List<int> visited = new List<int>(220000);            
            Q.Enqueue(start);            
            trace[start] =  -1;            
            visited[start] = 1;
            do
            {
                u = Q.Peek();
                Q.Dequeue();
                for (int v = 1; v <= nodes; ++v)
                {
                    if ((grid[u, v] == 1) && visited[v] == 0)
                    {
                        Q.Enqueue(v);
                        trace[v] = u;
                        visited[v] = 1;
                    }
                }
            } while (Q.Count != 0);
        }
```

The problem is that don't work. I have this error :

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

at here :

```
trace[start] =  -1;            
visited[start] = 1;
```

i called function in main :

```
static int Main()
        {

            List<int> trace = new List<int>(220);
            Queue<int> Q = new Queue<int>();
            int[,] grid = new int[582,582];                          

            int nodes;
            int vertices;
            Console.Write("Please input the number of Node : \n");

            nodes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            vertices = 200;
            Read_input_from_user(grid, vertices);
            int starting_position;
            int finishing_position;
            Console.Write("Please Input the Starting Node : \n");              
            starting_position = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Please Input the Finishing Node : \n");
            finishing_position = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Breadth_first_search(Q, trace, grid, starting_position, nodes);
            Trace_result(trace, starting_position, finishing_position, nodes);
            Console.ReadLine();
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: How are you calling this function? What value does `start` contain, and what is the size of `trace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user enters something that is greater than 220 as a starting position, this line

```
trace[start] =  -1;
```

will throw an exception, since `start` is indeed out of `trace` bounds. Therefore you need to force user to enter something you can handle. Like this:

```
Console.Write("Please Input the Starting Node : \n");
starting_position = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
while (starting_position < 0 || starting_position >= trace.Count)
{
    Console.Write("Starting Node is invalid. Should be between 0 and 220. Please enter another one  : \n");
    starting_position = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

This is just an idea, point is - you should think about user input validation so it does not break your program.

**Update.** Actually I did not realize that `trace` in the code above contains no entries at all. Which means that calling it with any index will produce an error - if list does not contain elements at all, it is obviously impossible to call one or set its value. So while it is still true that you should have a validation mechanism for the user input, the main problem here is how the list is treated. Here are the ways to resolve it:

1. You can initialize list with same value, say 0:

   ```
   List<int> trace = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 220).ToList();
   ```
2. Or you can use array instead of list:

   ```
   int[] trace = new int[220];
   ```

Comment: @mahdad, sorry, I did not realize the problem was elsewhere. Please see the update